# Unwanted capacitance in measurement setup - what to consider?

Tags: current-measurement, capacitance

I have a current measurement setup (which supposed to measure < 1nA). It has 20 channels and switched using a relay matrix.

Using a LCR meter I measured for one channel (In the schematic below, removing capacitor and putting LCR probes in series), and it happend in open mode, the whole setup capacitance is **6pF** and if a chanel is closed (Obviously when taking a measurement, the respective channel is closed) the capacitance is around **50pF**

[image]

I really would like to know how this capacitance (which I beleive comes accumulated from 22 coaxial cables, roughly 20 meters and count the internal wiring of test setup) can affect/contribute to my measurement? What is the theory behind it (I want to study it further) and possible workarounds?

Here is the schematic of my setup:

[image]

Comment: In theory the capacitance should affect only dynamic measurements, and 50 pF should be significative only if you have high enough frequency signals (>1 MHz). But with this setup i don't think you will achieve the <1 nA accuracy.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell more about the problems stopping this setup from reading sub-nano? The instruments are all rated for sub-nano...I know my test setup itself does not look good enough :(

Comment: I think that at first you should carefully check the ground loops that occur when you connect more ground pins together. How are you grounding your cables? Second, i think that the cables themselves are a bit long...You are dealing with SMALL currents...

Comment: Can I contact you directly? I guess you are at fontys right?

Answer (score 2):

- Use a star point for ground; with such small currents, the smallest impedance in the wire will distort your measurement.
- Terminate your coax cables properly; your coax cables are highly frequency dependend when you don't.
- You might want to use a high impedance amplifier near the device under test (DUT), like an active probe, FET-probe or something similar to drive the cables.
- When measuring such small signals, you might want to try to change the setup into a bridge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge